# Flat window removal from time series

Tags: time-series, unevenly-spaced-time-series, intermittent-time-series, timeseries-segmentation

I have a time series that I'm using for forecasting and I'm facing an issue with a flat period.

In my time series, I have the following dynamic: In the past the quantity was stationary (red part), almost intermittent but there's some data; however after some time the series started to pick up and behave like a regular more "normal" time series.

I could visually inspect all series individually and remove this flat period for each one of them, but I would like to know if there's some way to so it systematically or some specific technique that I can use, since I have more than 1500+ time series.

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to remove this? What is your goal? What is your actual issue?

Comment: > What is your goal? 
Essentially due to this dynamic, the "straight" of the tren, seasonality becomes weaker even for the short period of time forecast. So the goal is to capture recent and more important trends and seasonality.  

For some series I removed and the results converged with unseen data, but using this quite long series in red distorts the results.